# Leaflet.js map - Pan too and Zoom in on point

Tags: leaflet

This is the first time I am using Leaflet.js. I am trying to create a story map but have come across an issue.

Currently I have a map with a scrolling text bar on the left hand side. I would like users to be able to scroll through the text on the left and when they click on a part of the text it will automatically pan too and zoom in on the correct area on the map, at the same time displaying the marker.

Comment: What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? Have you tried the `setView` method on the map?

Comment: [SetView](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview) is what you are looking for, I think, as you haven't really stated what is the text being clicked on.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is:

```
var marker = L.marker([lat, lng],{}).addTo(map);
map.flyTo([lat, lng], zoom);
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is a pattern that may be useful. Data attributes provide a kind of 'self-configuring' behavior. The example here uses jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<div class="story" data-point="37.000,-120.652">First story. Click to zoom</div>
<div class="story" data-point="35.232,-118.334">Another story. Click to zoom</div>
<div class="story" data-point="35.232,-118.334">Another story. Click to zoom</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// basic map setup. include other options as needed, refer to the docs
var map = L.map('map');

// bind click event to the story divs, add a marker and zoom to that story's location. Remember to add dot before story as it is classname
$('.story').on('click', function(){
    // parse lat and lng from the divs data attribute
    var latlng = $(this).data().point.split(',');
    var lat = latlng[0];
    var lng = latlng[1];
    var zoom = 10;

    // add a marker
    var marker = L.marker([lat, lng],{}).addTo(map);
    // set the view
    map.setView([lat, lng], zoom);
})
```

Comment: set view won't actually PAN the map to the point but will _jump_ to it. `panTo` is what you want to use instead. Works just like setView but will pan to the place (if possible/not too far away, I think) instead of jumping

Comment: One tiny nit, you don't actually need to create separate `lat` and `lng` variables after you split the lat/lon string from the `data-point` attribute since you're just recombining them in the same order when creating the marker. You could just do `var marker = L.marker($(this).data().point.split(','),{}).addTo(map);` to remove 3 out of the 6 lines of code in the click handler.

Answer (score 2):

As @Daniele Ding pointed out, you can use `panTo` to let the user navigates to the desired location smoothly, rather than jumping from point to point, which is considered more pleasant user experience.

Basic example:

```
map.panTo(latlng);
```

In my case, I needed to let the user to navigate to drawn shape on the map, and I used:

```
var layer = polygonsGroup.getLayers()[0];
var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs()[0];
var latlng = L.latLng(latlngs[0]);
MapEngine.map.panTo(latlng);
layer.setStyle({
    color: "#FFFF00",
    fillColor: "#FFFF7F"
});
```

Comment: `panTo()` just wraps `setView()` with the current zoom level.  https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.9.3/src/map/Map.js#L308 But any method which ultimately results in a call to `_animateZoom()` will be restricted to the hardcoded 250ms. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.9.3/src/map/Map.js#L308

Comment: Actually, `flyTo()` does the job and the duration can be specified.