# Click on external div link to Zoom to feature (or lat/long)

Tags: leaflet

I want to click on a link in a navigation div in order to zoom to a location within my leaflet map.

Html:

```
<div class="sidebar-nav">
     <div class="story" data-point="40.7451, -73.949">First link</div>
     <div class="story" data-point="40.7451, -73.949">Second link</div>
</div>

<div id="map">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//initialize map
var map = L.map('map', {
  zoomControl: true
}).setView([40.7451, -73.9459], 16);

var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19
}).addTo(map);

//click and zoom        
$('story').on('click', function(){
    // parse lat and lng from the divs data attribute
    var latlng = $(this).data().point.split(',');
    var lat = latlng[0];
    var lng = latlng[1];
    var zoom = 10;

    // set the view
    map.setView([lat, lng], zoom);
  })
```

I am using: 
jQuery v3.2.1 
leaflet v0.7.7

When I click on the div nothing happens. Forgive me if there is an obvious solution, I have brand-new to java-script.

I'm attempting to use a solution originally posted here:
[Leaflet.js map - Pan too and Zoom in on point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147052/leaflet-js-map-pan-too-and-zoom-in-on-point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your leaflet code along with jquery needs just one modification.

Just **add a dot** in on click function (as you are using a class name) as below:

```
$('.story').on('click', function(){
```

I would recomment you to use a trim() function in your latlng[] array i.e, latlng[0].trim() and latlng[1].trim(). Now it will work as your code has been tested.